# Rich snippets for website structure

Tags: html, seo, rich-snippets

I've recently discovered rich snippets and their usage to make a search motor understand
the type of content such as addresses, people,...

I have a website in which for each page I replicate the menu (A simple menu with links to all the pages ~20 of the website)
Since the first element in the `body` is the menu, Google makes the same search preview for all the pages: the menu and not the actual content of the page.

So I would like to know if there is a way to tell the search motor the structure of the page: for instance that some elements are navigation elements, some are content, some are copyright...
Describing the "human" structure of the page.

What I understood is that rich snippets are intended to describe "real life" information, and what I am searching would be something similar but to describe the structure.

I hope that make sens.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I would like to know if there is a way to tell the search motor the structure of the page: for instance that some elements are navigation elements, some are content, some are copyright... Describing the "human" structure of the page.

Well, this is what HTML elements are used for. Some use the term "semantic markup/HTML" for this. Of course this has its limits, as not *every* kind of structure/content type can be described.

Solutions for your example:

- For navigation, there is the [`nav` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element).
- The main content of a page can be automatically found thanks to [sections](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#sections) and the [outline algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#outlines) (in HTML 5.1 there is also the [`main` element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-main-element)).
- The copyright info should be given in the [`small` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element), probably in a [`footer` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element). If it's a link to a license, you should use the [`license` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-license).

In general, you should follow these steps (from structure to content):

1. use appropriate HTML elements, as detailed as possible
2. use defined/registered [link types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes) (for `link`, `a` and `area` elements)
3. use [Microformats](http://microformats.org/) (`class` attribute values for all elements)
4. use defined/registered [meta tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element) (in `meta` elements)
5. use [RDFa (Lite)](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/) and/or [Microdata](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/) (new attributes for all elements)

[WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) can give additional info about your structure intended for accessibility.

Comment: Thanks for your very nice and complete answer. I have read about Microformats, and I found quite bizarre and kind of confusing that it uses class attributes, which I thought were primarily intended to style elements. Do you still think it is a good practice or should I prefer other methods?

Comment: @user1843507: Yeah, that's right – microformats are quick-and-dirty, a loosely defined convention. If you find some Microformats that could be used for your content, you could add the relevant `class` values quickly (→ won't hurt, may help). But I wouldn't bother paying too much attention, as this would be better invested into [RDFa or Microdata](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14501684/1591669). You could totally skip this step and don't use Microformats at all.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
<meta name="description" content="A description of the page" />
```

This tag provides a short description of the page. In some situations this description is used as a part of the snippet shown in the search results.
Google will take that string and will show it in the search results

Comment: Ah yes I thought about that, nevertheless that is not exactly what I am searching for since some page are generated automatically and I cannot ask the user to put a proper description. The ideal solution would really be that in the body of each page I would be able to describe what is the purpose of the html elements. But if there is no such thing then yes I guess I would have to go with that solution.